# Почему не работает ООП slider?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ооп

Пытаюсь сделать ООП слйдер, но возникает какая-то проблема. Ошибок в консоли нет. При нажатии на кнопку "Назад" слайдер не реагирует, что я делаю не правильно? (Был бы благодарен, если бы указали и на другие ошибки).

```js
function Slider(sliderClass, slides, arrows, btnPerv, btnNext) {
  this.sliderWrap = document.querySelector(sliderClass);
  this.slides = document.querySelectorAll(slides);
  this.arrows = arrows;
  this.btnPerv = document.querySelector(btnPerv);
  this.btnNext = document.querySelector(btnNext);
  this.btnPerv.addEventListener('click', this.slideNext);
  this.slideNext = function() {
for ( var i = 0; i < this.slides.length; i++) {
  if (this.slides[i].classList.contains('slides-active')) {
    this.slides[i].classList.remove('slides-active');
  }
}
  }
}

var topSlider = new Slider('.slider_one', '.slider_one .slides', true, '.perv', '.next');
console.log(topSlider);
```

```css
.slider_one {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.slides {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.slides-active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slides-1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.slides-2 {
   background-color: blue;
}

.slides-3 {
   background-color: green;
} 

.slides-4 {
   background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider_one">
  <div class="slides slides-1 slides-active"></div>
  <div class="slides slides-2"></div>
  <div class="slides slides-3"></div>
  <div class="slides slides-4"></div>
</div>
 <button class="perv">Назад</button>
 <button class="next">Вперед</button>


<div class="slider_two">
  <div class="slides"></div>
  <div class="slides"></div>
  <div class="slides"></div>
  <div class="slides"></div>
</div>
```

[Ссылка на сниппет](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ELaEBB?editors=1111)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var"

**for**

```
this.slideNext = function() {
  **for** ( var i = 0; i < this.slides.length; i++) {
```

*Update*

Много неправильного.

1. Начнем с того, что куда "назад" тут можно двигаться, если мы находимся на первом слайде?
2. Нет обработчика для кнопки "Вперед".
3. Обработчик `slideNext` вызывается в контексте, где не тот `this`. Надо:

   ```
   this.btnPerv.addEventListener('click', this.slideNext.bind(this));
   ```
4. Обе кнопки накрыты вторым слайдером, и клики в них не попадают.
5. В момент выполнения `this.btnPerv.addEventListener('click', this.slideNext);` метод `this.slideNext` еще не определен, так что в `addEventListener` передается `undefined`.

И это я еще не смотрел на логику кода в обработчике.

Comment: В сниппете for проставлено, видимо я старую версию скопировал сюда, сейчас обновлю, но даже с for не работает

Comment: обновил сниппет на борде

Comment: спасибо, но я не делал слайдер до конца, кнопка "назад" должна была удалить всем элементам определенный класс, и всё) Остальное я пока что еще просто напросто не делал)